# Help with Wordpress RSS Validation Error

Tags: rss, validation

I was trying to link my site (http://neontoday.com) to Bloglovin. However it wasn't showing my post, so I emailed support and I was told there was an issue with RSS validation for my site.

I have looked everywhere and tried out plugins and stuff and nothing seems to work.

Can anyone please help out?

Here is the link to the Validation checker to see for yourself: http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.neontoday.com%2Ffeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the validator output, you will see there is a little red arrow pointing to the space between "knows" and "me". Copy "knows me" to a simple text editor like Notepad and you will see that the blank space consists of two characters, a space and an unknown invisible one.

To get rid of the last one, delete "knows me" and retype it, making sure you are not hitting any weird keys on your keyboard.

Comment: Brilliant! That fixed it. Thak=anks so much for your help!